# What's a Backup and Recovery Process for Team Foundation Server 2010?

Tags: tfs, backup, restore, database-restore

We have a new installation of TFS 2010 (on SQL Server 2008), and I'm planning the backup and recovery process.

It seems the configuration information and data is stored in the Tfs_Configuration and Tfs_DefaultCollection databases (and additional Tfs_[CollectionName] dbs if you have more than one collection). In a test setup, I tried backing up the two dbs, uninstalling TFS, then reinstalling (thinking I could then hook the databases up at some point in the install process). This is where I'm confused. I don't see an option or clear guidance on how this is suppose to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download the [TFS Power tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f/) and [use the backup tool](http://myalmblog.com/2010/09/12/tfs-2010-power-tools-tfs-backup-and-restore-hands-on-lab/) (it's even got a nice GUI)!

Comment: I originally posted the question before this tool was available, but it looks very nice. I actually thought about switching to it, but our TFS databases are hosted on a shared database server which we have a common backup plan for, so I decided to stick with out conventional db backup scheme.

Comment: @Derek, just be careful about using a conventional db backup scheme and make sure all three databases are backed up at the time transactionally or you could have back ups that are out of sync.

Comment: Very good point. That could really bite you if you're not careful. Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 9):

If you have backed up your TFS 2010 databases and lose your TFS server, you can restore it by restoring all of your TFS databases, reinstalling TFS, and selecting the Application Tier option of the installation wizard. Once you point the wizard at your database, it will recognize the Tfs_Configuration database from the previous installation and restore your previous configuration as well as your collections.

Comment: What about the Build Server? Is there any data that needs to be backed up there?

Comment: Good point. We're not using TFS Build yet, so I haven't looked into this. Would love to hear info about this.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a MSDN section on this topic: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552295.aspx